# paymentQueue:queue updatedTransactions:transactions never called

Tags: cocoa, in-app-purchase, osx-leopard

I have migrated functioning in-app purchasing code from iOS to OSX but this function is never called:

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions

I have:

- created a new version of the app in iTunes Connect. It is in "Waiting for Upload" state;
- created an in-app purchase item (non-consumable) in iTunes Connect. It is in "Ready to Submit" state;
- created a test user;
- checked the console, but messages don't seem related to the in-app purchase;
- the code includes [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

What else have I missed to do or check ?

Answer (score 0):

firstly are you making your request? its like

```
SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:@"com.sestek.aaaa"]];
```

and then you have to use this method for request

```
-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
```

response will fall in here and then  call your

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
```

Comment: That's exactly what I do and works on iOS. On OSX nothing happens. I have removed the In-app purchase item and everything started working for a couple of days. Then, nothing again.